# How to wait on a process handle in javascript

Tags: javascript, child-process

I am creating a process from a javascript. Is there any way to know when the process execution has been completed?

In win32 we can wait of the process handle using [`waitforsingleobject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and know when the process execution is completed. I am looking for something similar in javascript.

Following is the code snippet

```
var retValue = process.Create(shellCmd);
```

Here I need to know when the process has completed its execution.

Comment: I have never heard about processes in client side JavaScript. Please provide more information.

Comment: This would appear to concern the Child Process API in node.js. The documentation has information on event-handling. http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: There is no good idea to mix javascript syntax and C++ API in code snippet: `var retValue = process.Create(shellCmd);`

Comment: @Pinal Where did you get the idea C++ is involved? Who added the tag?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh, @Pinal: Instead of *assuming* that the OP means node.js or something related with C++, why don't you guys let them clarify what they mean? Going from `jquery` to `c++ node.js win32-process` is a rather big step.

Comment: I removed jQuery (obviously unrelated). Googled exact example code --> Child Process API from node.js. (Not exactly a leap). C++ on the other hand?!

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: When I literally search for `var retValue = process.Create(shellCmd);`, I don't find anything related to Node.js. As you can see by Daniel's answer, the process control API in Node.js is quite different.

Comment: You fail at searching.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: Please enlighten me then.

Comment: Searching for that on google (no quotes) gives me that result (paraphrased, link I gave above) on the 1st page (near the bottom).

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: Not for me... maybe some personalization issue, who knows. As I already said, that Node.js module has a very different API. It doesn't even have a `Create` function (and FWIW, the term "shellCmd" doesn't even appear on that page, so it seems that "process" (and arguable "create") is the only term that occurs there, which is not a very strong match)

Comment: @David-SkyMesh  There is not a .Create method in the node `child_process` module.  *You* fail at searching, it seems.  http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: It simply came up as a match in the search. And, look there, it (the API I linked above) is the accepted answer. I didn't say there was a `Create` method in that API, only that I found it by pasting the OP's code into google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Child Process module.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var dir   = spawn('dir', []);

dir.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```